# Who wins a league (EPL) if two teams have the same number of points?

Tags: rules, football, ranking, english-premier-league, tie-breaker

Is there any rule defined by **UEFA** or **FIFA**?

> If more teams have the same number of points in a league after the finishing game, what is the rule to declare a winner??

Were there any rule updates by UEFA for this season (2013/14) or the upcoming season?

I found on the Premier League official website: [Who wins the League if teams have the same number of points?](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/fans/faqs/who-wins-league-if-teams-finish-on-same-points.html)

Here the rule is defined by goal difference. Is it a new rule, or is it determined by **head-to-head** then **goal difference**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If two or more teams end up with same points in points table, then team having more **Goal Difference** i.e., **Goals Scored minus Goals Against**, wins the title.

if **Goal Differences** are also same for those teams, then team having more **Goals Scored** would win the title.

And if **Goals Scored** are also same for those teams, then all those teams on top having same points, same goal differences and goals scored would compete in a play-off match at a neutral ground. Note that, a play-off match is played only if there is a tie for championship, relegation, or qualification to other competitions. Otherwise tied teams are considered to occupy the same position.

Reference: [English Premier League Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League)

**History:**

**1. [2011-12 EPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011%E2%80%9312_Premier_League), Manchester City and Manchester United**: 
Manchester City won the title by having +8 goal difference.

**2. [1988-89 EPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988%E2%80%9389_in_English_football), Arsenal and Liverpool**: 
Arsenal won the league championship on goals-scored, after finishing level on points and goal-difference with Liverpool.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this rule is also applied fro LaLiga(Premier Division) also . or not?

Comment: Rule is different in La Liga.. If the tie is between two clubs, then the tie is broken using the goal difference for the two matches those clubs have played against each other without 'away goals rule'.

Comment: La Liga has complex rules for tie breaking. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Liga for detailed info

Comment: In argentina they have to play one against the other.. If more than two teams share the points, then you have 3 matches to resolve the winning. (this happens about two years ago). There is no more goal differences for resolving anything here.

Answer (score 4):

The Premier League rulebook states:

> If at the end of the Season, either the League Champions or the Clubs to be relegated or the question of qualification for other competitions cannot be determined because 2 or more Clubs are equal on points, goal difference and goals scored, the Clubs concerned shall play off one or more deciding League Matches on neutral grounds, the format, timing and venue of which shall be determined by the Board."

There is [an article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/chelsea/11320967/Why-are-Chelsea-top-of-the-Premier-League-above-Manchester-City.html) explaining how Chelsea and Manchester City will face-off for the title with completely level stats.

Answer (score 3):

In the EPL/Premier League if two teams are equal on points, goal difference and goals scored and the position is of value (deemed, winners, champions league automatic qualification, champions league vs Europa league or relegation) then a head to head playoff would be arranged.  If this looks likely before the last weekend of the season then contingency plans are initiated, the last time was 2013 when it was considered. [(sportinglife)](http://www.sportinglife.com/football/news/article/165/8713867/play-off-chance-in-premier-league)

If more than two are equal then the EPL board would declare a mini league knock out to determine the position.

Neither scenario has ever occured, the closest was in 1996 between Man U and Newcastle.

NOTE: These are the EPL rules and did NOT apply to pre-EPL.  The EPL can NEVER be shared, there MUST be a winner