# Theoretically, what is the maximum number of times any two English Premier League teams can play each other in a single season?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

Assuming that the two teams are eligible for every available competition, and including every scenario (such as cup replays, etc.), what would be the maximum number of times that two teams from the English Premier League could play each other in a single season?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, let's work this out logically:

- 1 [FA Community Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FA_Community_Shield) match
- 3 [Premier League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League) matches (2 round-robin +  if there is a tie for championship, relegation, or qualification to other competitions, additional play-off match is played. See [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/who-wins-a-league-epl-if-two-teams-have-the-same-number-of-points))
- 2 [League Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFL_Cup) matches (semi-final with 2 legs)
- 2 [FA Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FA_Cup) matches (1 tie + replay)
- 2 [Champions League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League) / [Europa League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Europa_League) matches (2 legs of the knockout round, because teams from the same association cannot be drawn into the same group for Champions League or Europa League. See [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/can-two-teams-from-the-same-league-be-drawn-in-the-same-champions-league-group))
- 1 [UEFA Super Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Super_Cup) match (if one side won the Champions League and another the Europa League in the previous season)

That's **11** matches.

Comment: Initially I did think 4 Champions League, but then I remembered teams from the same league can't be in the same group... assuming I remembered correctly? In addition I have read somewhere about there being a potential league playoff for final position in the event points, GD and GF and all equal (and final position is important for qualification/relegation). I forgot about charity shield though

Comment: Is it possible for teams in the same Champions League group to meet in the quarter finals?

Comment: @musefan Correct; the Premier League will have playoffs if necessary; the details aren't specified, so there could even be more than one match.

Comment: @PhilipKendall according to the champions league website it's a free draw from the qf onwards, the round between the groups and the quarter finals two teams couldn't meet from the same group

Comment: Nobody seems to be addressing the issue that 2 teams from the same league **cannot** play in the same champions league group... or am I making that rule up?

Comment: @musefan You've asked a good question on that elsewhere. Let's see what happens here and then fix this answer up as appropriate.

Comment: @BenWhyall: I think if you could add something about the potential for 1 or more playoff games at the end of the season (as hinted [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/12201/685) and mentioned above by Philip) then your answer would be pretty solid and I can accept it

Comment: Sorry to pop up with another caveat for you - and for not being around much lately, but... You could play a team again if the game was abandoned.  This happened to my team, Sunderland. [Original match](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/eng_prem/4957438.stm) and [replayed match](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/eng_prem/4867558.stm). We played Fulham 3 times in the Premier League that season.

Comment: From 2007 take part to FIFA Club World Cup the six winner teams of continental competition and host nation team, so if the competition is hosted by England and an English team has won the last Championship league can take part two english teams

Comment: If you go here: http://www.fifa.com/clubworldcup/clubs/index.html at the section Road to Japan under the Asia map, the site speaks about Guangzhou Evergrande and Sanfrecce Hiroshima.

Answer (score -3):

- BPL: 2+1 playoff in case of a tie in points, GD and goals scored.
- Community Shield: 1
- FA Cup: 2 with a replay
- League Cup: 2, in a semi-final;could be three if the semi-final can have a third match (see the Champions League section)
- Club World Cup: If it was hosted in England, the teams could meet. (1)
- CL: Now this is the one that noone's gotten so far: The teams could face each other up to 5 times; it is possible for two clubs from the same country to play in the same group, IF the other team qualified as the winner of the Europa League. Then there's the possibility of a quarter- or a semi-final with a third match played in the case of aggregate goals being tied after the fielding(s) of ineligible players changing result(s) to 3-0.
- UEFA Super Cup: 1

I count that as 15 or 16, depending on whether a League Cup semi-final can have a replay.

Comment: Could you provide a citation for your assertions about the Champions League? The question linked from Ben Whyall's answer is pretty explicit in writing the rulebook which says that two teams from the same national association *cannot* be in the same group; ditto for your assertions about a third match.

Comment: Yeah, these are pretty interesting suggestions if you could provide some references to back them up? Particularly ability to play in same CL group, and that a 3rd CL knockout round match could occur if the first 2 legs are defaulted