# Can two teams from the same league be drawn in the same champions league group?

Tags: football, champions-league

I was sure the answer to my question is "No", but I can't seem to find any concrete resources to confirm it either way.

Is it possible for two teams from the same domestic league to be drawn to play against each other in the same group of the Champions League?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the 2015/16 UEFA Champions League competition, two teams from the same domestic league may not be drawn to play in the same group. Furthermore, two teams from the same national association (even if they are in different domestic leagues, eg. the Premier League and the Football League Championship) also may not play in the same group.

From the [Regulations of the UEFA Champions League 2015/16 (pdf)](http://www.uefa.org/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/23/57/51/2235751_DOWNLOAD.pdf), p. 22:

> ## Article 16  Match system – group stage
>
> 16.01 Once the play-offs have been completed, the 32 remaining clubs are drawn into eight groups of four in accordance with Paragraph 13.05. **Clubs from the same association cannot be drawn into the same group.**

Comment: This is also true for UEFA Europa League Competition. See UEFA Europa League Regualtions, _Article 15, Match system - Group Stage_ [http://www.uefa.org/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/23/69/59/2236959_DOWNLOAD.pdf]

Comment: Great find thanks, as you mention play-offs, do you know if it would be possible for two teams in the same national association could play each other in the play-offs?

Comment: There is no mention of this being prevented in the regulations, but it is impossible, given how the places in the qualifying and play-off rounds are allocated. There are two routes through the qualifying and play-off rounds, and at present, an association may only have one team enter each route as you can see here http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/accesslist/index.html

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it's still possible but in the [2005/2006 Champions League](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005%E2%80%9306_UEFA_Champions_League) group stage both Chelsea and Liverpool were in group G along with Betis Sevilla and Anderlecht.

This was possible because Liverpool lost their protection because they did not finish in a CL qualifying position in the league, but did win the CL the year before.

Comment: That's a good point, if the previous season's winner is treated as a 'non-association' special case I suppose they wouldn't be considered to be conflicting with any other team in their league/association. It would be great to find a reference that proves this to be right or wrong for current standards though

Answer (score -3):

When clubs of the same league or Association arbe drawn in the same group,,they are not to play before confirmation from the Champions board of Regulations,,,

Comment: This answer need clarification and a link giving a reference to back it up, otherwise it's liable to be deleted.